# Can any distance be expressed by the product scalar or inner scalar?

Tags: distance, linear-algebra, metric

I know that a distance could be expressed by inner scalars or scalar products. Is this true for all metrics (i.e., respecting the three axioms: the identity of indiscernible, symmetry, triangle inequality), e.g., Euclidean distance, Manhattan, Mahalanobis? Same question for a distance not respecting the triangle inequality, e.g., Bray-Curtis distance...?

An example of the expression of a distance by inner scalar is the square Euclidean distance:
$||a-b||^2=<a,a>+<b,b>-2<a,b>$ with $a,b \in R^d$